# Django ORM querying nested models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to use django ORM to filter some records from db,
I have a model named `User` which contain a field `profile` which is another model,
When I do the following I get all the users having a profile:

`users = User.objects.filter(Q(profile__isnull=False))`

`profile` has a field `age`
I want to delete all the users with a profile and age>30.
So I looped through all the users with a profile and then checked if their age is > 30.

```
for user in  users:
    if user.profile.age>30:
          user.delete()
```

Is there a way to use `user.profile.age>30` directly in querying?

Comment: Try: `User.objects.filter(Q(profile__isnull=False) & Q(profile__age__gt=30))`

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by combining `Q` objects from `Django` as followings:

```
User.objects.filter(Q(profile__isnull=False) & Q(profile__age__gt=30))
```